# How do I accept and complete missions in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I didn't get how to work with the missions's menu.
I want to do the income increase mission but how do I accept it and how do I see my progress and requierments?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens automatically. If after a battle you have sucessfully fulfilled the requirements and objectives, you will complete the mission. Some missions are limited, others can be completed as much as you like.

The exception to this, are the new **personal missions**, which behave differently.

You will find these in the upper left corner of your screen, when you are in your garage. You can unlock four new tanks, but in order. In the beginning, only the *StuG IV* (per time of writing) is available to start unlocking, so when you click on that, you will get a list of missions.

[image: World of Tanks personal missions]

There are fifteen missions for each tank type, and these have to be completed in order. To start a mission, click on it, and there should be a "start mission" button (it will be where the "cancel" button is in the screenshot above). When you have started the mission, it will automatically complete after a battle, so you don't have to worry about it.

When a mission is completed, you have to manually start a new mission as before.

Comment: thanks!! helped me alot, though about the income increase mission i didnt get where can I check the requierments to win